# MySQL connect 2 different tables to a 3rd one

Tags: mysql, database

A client or a provider (clients_table, providers_table) can have many phone numbers, thus, I created a third table (phone_book) to store phone numbers (landline, mobile) but I'm stuck in how to create/manage relationships between the 3 tables.
What is the best way to manage this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Create two pivot / link tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how similar/dissimilar the client and provider tables are, or if perhaps they might fit better as one single table.  I will explain a general way of handling your requirement.  Consider the following table definitions:

```
clients_table (id, name, address)
phone_book (id, number)
clients_phone (client_id, phone_id)
    (client_id -> clients_table, phone_id -> phone_book)
```

That is, create a new *junction* table called `clients_phone` which keeps track of the relationships between clients and their phones.  Note that with this design, we do not have to repeat the phone information anywhere.  It appears only once, in the `phone_book` table.

The above design might have to change slightly given that there is a provider table as well.

Comment: Thanks Tim,
the 2 tables have different fields (e.g. provider's VAT, client's scheme...), I thought about a junction table but then I'll end up with 2 more tables (client_phone, provider_phone). I thought maybe there is a cleaner way of doing it

Comment: Separate tables for clients and providers looks suspicious to me.  If instead you just had a single table containing both clients and providers, then you could use my answer directly.

Comment: That would work but some differences can't go unseen such as first and last names (customers) and companies names (providers) among other things that I mentioned some in my previous comment. Bottom line can't be merged. Actually I'm thinking about implementing a phone table with 1 PK and 2FK.